# Cannot import tensorflow inside the project folder

Tags: python-3.x, linux, tensorflow, tf.keras

I can import tensorflow in my home directory but when I change to project directory I am getting import error as you can see in below screenshot

[image]

You can see the project folder content also in the screenshot, even if I remove the `__pycache__` folder it recreates it again with the same error.
Last line of error:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'constant' from partially initialized module 'tensorflow.python.framework.constant_op' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/prakhar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py)`  
Version details:

- Python version: 3.8.2

  Tensorflow version: 2.3.1

  No CUDA installed since I do not need GPU support

Comment: what is the absolute path of your project? To me it looks like you are creating your files inside a virtual Environmenth "Python" "Scripts"..or even the actual python installation path

Comment: @AndreyBulezyuk Thats just a directory name inside my home folder

Comment: Weird. Can you go to another random Path like Documents/somefolder/ and try doing the same?

Comment: @AndreyBulezyuk after I renamed `code.py` to other name, it worked without problem, is there a problem with filename `code.py`

Comment: I think code.py is already defined in python packages - https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/code.py , that is the reason after you renamed it must have worked.

Comment: @TFer That may be the case, but I have other projects also with `code.py` in it and works fine but did not used tensorflow, maybe some libraries gives error if `code.py` is present and others work fine

Comment: did anyone find the solution for this?

Comment: @HououinKyouma You can check the above comments, I renamed `code.py` and it worked for me.