# Cannot import name 'constant' from partially initialized module 'tensorflow.python.framework.constant_op'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've installed tensorflow and keras in a virtual environment, but when I try to run `from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model` I get the following error:

```
from tensorflow.python.framework.constant_op import constant
ImportError: cannot import name 'constant' from partially initialized module 'tensorflow.python.framework.constant_op' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py)
```

I'm running tensorflow version 2.4.0 and Keras 2.4.3 and python 3.8.7

I've uninstalled and reinstalled both tensorflow and keras, but still no chance! Any idea how I can find what's causing this issue?

P.S. This is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import data
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data import experimental
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/__init__.py", line 96, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.experimental import service
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/service/__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.data_service_ops import distribute
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/ops/data_service_ops.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops import compression_ops
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/ops/compression_ops.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.util import structure
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/util/structure.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.util import nest
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/util/nest.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import sparse_tensor as _sparse_tensor
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/sparse_tensor.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import constant_op
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import execute
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 63, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import app
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 23, in <module>
    from absl.app import run as _run
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 35, in <module>
    import pdb
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/pdb.py", line 77, in <module>
    import code
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/code.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/keras/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import activations
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/keras/activations/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.activations import deserialize
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import models
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client import session as session_module
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops import session_ops
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/session_ops.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
  File "/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.constant_op import constant
ImportError: cannot import name 'constant' from partially initialized module 'tensorflow.python.framework.constant_op' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/Gabriel/Development/Projects/Keras-FaceNet_demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64555814/cannot-import-tensorflow-inside-the-project-folder sounds similar

Comment: how are you running that import statement? is it in a file? if so, what's the filename?

Comment: Is this really the complete error message? If not, show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: I'm running a file called: `code.py`, this is the entire file: from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('facenet_keras.h5')
print(model.inputs)
print(model.outputs)

Comment: I've edited the post with full error message

Comment: rename your file to something different than `code.py` - same problem as the linked question in my first comment

Comment: wow... thank you! That was really weird.

Answer (score 7):

From Comments

> [code.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/code.py)
> is already defined in python packages. Hence after renaming `code.py`
> file to something other name has resolved the problem (paraphrased
> from Macattack).